# Get constant incoming post requests from multiple devices with Django Rest Framework or listen TCP Server Socket

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, tcpsocket

I have IoT devices which are rfıd readers. This devices send stream data with  HTTP Post message.  I use Django to get data from these devices. While receiving this data, I can write a function to get data from post requests coming directly with Django and receive the data from the request in this function with Django REST Framework or I can listen with a TCP Server socket. Which of these two approaches is more suitable for retrieving data? Because when I use a TCP Server socket, Django REST Framework does not work for HTTP requests, only the TCP socket works.

Comment: "Django REST Framework does not work for HTTP requests" why it does not work?

Comment: @MaratMkhitaryan listen post request using TCP Server Socket. Django REST Framework does not get any request.

Comment: yeah, if DRF does not work just use asyncio tcp server. It's much easier to write a tcp server using asyncio. Actually DRF is not suitable for such low level cases and TCP server should be used instead. Or you can integrate directly to the WSGI and use some more low level library like CherryPy.